# Regular expression syntax for "match nothing"?

Tags: python, regex

I have a python template engine that heavily uses regexp. It uses concatenation like:

```
re.compile( regexp1 + "|" + regexp2 + "*|" + regexp3 + "+" )
```

I can modify the individual substrings (regexp1, regexp2 etc).

Is there any small and light expression that matches nothing, which I can use inside a template where I don't want any matches? Unfortunately, sometimes '+' or '*' is appended to the regexp atom so I can't use an empty string - that will raise a "nothing to repeat" error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723182/a-regex-that-will-never-be-matched-by-anything

Comment: Could the title be better worded as "Regular expression to fail to match anything"?  Matching nothing implies a successful match of an empty string.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

This shouldn't match anything:

```
re.compile('$^')
```

So if you replace regexp1, regexp2 and regexp3 with '$^' it will be impossible to find a match. Unless you are using the multi line mode.

---

After some tests I found a better solution

```
re.compile('a^')
```

It is impossible to match and will fail earlier than the previous solution. You can replace a with any other character and it will always be impossible to match

Comment: That will not match anything for sure and is lightweight for regexp engine to process? (don't want my stub regexps to eat a lot of cpu)

Comment: @Eye of hell. It should be lightweight. This will try to match a line end followed by a line start. Which is impossible in one line.

Comment: But possible with multiple lines of course (depending on if the flag is enabled) - for a solution that works whether the flag is enabled or not, see my answer.

Comment: The regex "$^" matches the empty string, at least in some implementations. The second one is better.

Comment: @romkyns Second one does not match empty string in my call to PyQt4 `QtCore.QRegExp`. So bad, as it would surely have been lighter to execute.

Comment: This matches an empty string in ruby.

Comment: And in Java. Not sure why though.

Comment: I tried using "a^", but this does not work: That string matches itself! Apparently a ^ that's not at the beginning of a regular expression matches a normal ^ character. 
Instead, I found this to work: "^(?!x)x"

Comment: I'd recommend `re.compile('matchnothing^')` or similar to make it more readable for those of us not versed in regex-fu

Answer (score 63):

`(?!)` should always fail to match.  It is the zero-width negative look-ahead.  If what is in the parentheses matches then the whole match fails.  Given that it has nothing in it, it will fail the match for anything (including nothing).

Comment: Right, I was just going to post this too.  This is the best way, if your language supports lookaheads.  Likewise (?=) matches every string.

Answer (score 18):

To match an empty string - even in multiline mode - you can use `\A\Z`, so:

```
re.compile('\A\Z|\A\Z*|\A\Z+')
```

The difference is that `\A` and `\Z` are start and end of *string*, whilst `^` and `$` these can match start/end of *lines*, so `$^|$^*|$^+` could potentially match a string containing newlines (if the flag is enabled).

And to fail to match anything (even an empty string), simply attempt to find content before the start of the string, e.g:

```
re.compile('.\A|.\A*|.\A+')
```

Since no characters can come before \A (by definition), this will always fail to match.

Comment: Yours looks nicer than mine since I assume it would exit out faster than using end of line.

Comment: Peter, you use \z (lower-case) while my Python pocket guide tells me the end-of-string assertion is \Z (upper-case)?!

Comment: ThomasH, they both are end of string, but the uppercase version allows a trailing newline whilst the lowercase one does not.

Comment: Mh, interesting, I find this nowhere documented. Also, _re.search("boo\z", "fooboo")_ doesn't returns a match object, while _re.search("boo\Z", "fooboo)_ does. Rather, _re.search("boo\z", "foobooz")_ matches, which speaks to the fact that '\z' is simply interpreted as 'z', right?! (This is in Python 2.6).

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought Python was PCRE, but it turns out there's a few differences, and this is one of them. ( See 'Anchors'  at http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html )

Comment: Great. - As this question was somewhat Python-oriented, maybe you want to update your otherwise excellent answer.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe `'.{0}'`?

Comment: This would match an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

You could use
`\z..`
This is the absolute end of string, followed by two of anything

If `+` or `*` is tacked on the end this still works refusing to match anything

Comment: Why *two* of anything? IIRC `\z` doesn't allow trailing newlines, unlike `\Z`, so won't one suffice? Or this a strange defense against `*` (why are you guarding against that?)

Comment: this felt like the best solution for my rust implementation which didn't support the negative look ahead that i initially preferred. for reasons i don't comprehend `.\A|.\A*|.\A+` actually matched any string.

Answer (score 0):

Or, use some list comprehension to remove the useless regexp entries and join to put them all together. Something like:

```
re.compile('|'.join([x for x in [regexp1, regexp2, ...] if x != None]))
```

Be sure to add some comments next to that line of code though :-)