# Why does m/$./m give me unexpected behavior?

Tags: regex, perl

In [What regular expressions can never match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845078/what-regular-expression-can-never-match/)  `/$./` was given as a response.  I played around with that a bit, and discovered that the following two lines of code generate different output.  The second matches, but the first does not.  Can anyone explain why?

```
$ printf 'a\nb\n' | perl -0777 -ne 'print if m/$./m'
$ perl -0777 -e '$_="a\nb\n"; print if m/$./m'
```

Also, note that adding <> in the following causes the match to fail:

```
$ printf 'a\nb\n' | perl -0777 -e '$b = "a\nb\n"; say $b =~ m/$./m'
$ printf 'a\nb\n' | perl -0777 -e '$b = "a\nb\n"; <>; say $b =~ m/$./m'
```

(That is, the first prints '1', the second prints a blank line)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turning on warnings gives a clue about the reason:

```
$ printf 'a\nb\n' | perl -0777 -w -e 'use feature qw/say/; $b = "a\nb\n"; say $b =~ m/$./m'
Use of uninitialized value $. in regexp compilation at -e line 1.
1
```

You're using an undefined value in the regex. The sequence [**`$.` refers to the special variable for the line number of the last-accessed file handle**](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24.). It does *not* designate the regular expression for "end of line followed by any character." Since you haven't accessed any files, it's still undef, so the regex is empty. When you use the `-n` option, it effectively wraps the rest of the program in `while (<>) { ... }`, so you read `<>` and end up with `1` in `$.` because you've read one line.

When you say `<>` in the second attempt, you've accessed the stdin file handle. Now the regular expression is `m/1/m`, which doesn't match the input string.

Comment: You can use `-E` instead of `-e` which does the same thing as -e'use feature ':5.10'` => `perl -0777 -wE'$b = "a\nb\n"; say $b =~ m/$./m'`

Answer (score 6):

The `$.` in your regex is being parsed as the value of the special variable `$.` (`$INPUT_LINE_NUMBER`) rather than "end of line followed by any character."

Also note that the `/m` modifier changes the meaning of `$` from matching at the end of the string to matching a line-ending anywhere within the string. See [Modifiers](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) in perlre. This means that it is possible to have something after it (with the appropriate modifiers):

```
say "a\nb\n" =~ m/$ ./msx;
```

prints "1". The `/x` modifier permits the use of embedded whitespace so we can separate the `$` from the `.` to avoid it being interpreted as a variable.

Answer (score 5):

This code print "broken pipe" for me, because perl doen't expect any input here. It also uses undefined variable `$.` (you'll see it if you'll add `-w` switch to perl). This variable `$.` represents current line number then reading lines by `<...>`. That's why it's undefined in this example:

```
## matching pattern will look like m//m
printf 'a\nb\n' | perl -0777 -e '$b = "a\nb\n"; say $b =~ m/$./m'
```

Following code reads pipe data, but will not match because `$.` became equal to 1 after `<>`. And the matching pattern became `m/1/m`:

```
## matching patter will be m/1/m, which is not found in $b value
printf 'a\nb\n' | perl -0777 -e '$b = "a\nb\n"; <>; say $b =~ m/$./m'
```

**Update:**

Use `m'$.'m` or `m/$ ./mx` (thanks to Michael Carman) to disable variable interpolation.

Comment: Of course! Special variable `$.`!  How would one write the regexp, then? Using `m'$.'` ?

Comment: `/\$./` parses as "literal '$' followed by any character" You can use the `/x` modifier to separate them, though: `m/$ ./x`

Answer (score 0):

<strike>In the first instance I believe it's because of the -n switch. In other words</strike>

```
printf 'a\nb\n' | perl -0777 -ne 'print if m/$./m'
```

Causes $_ to get the value `a\n` the first time through the loop and `b\n` the second time so clearly that won't match. Whereas with /m $ matches the \n in the second example so that's why that matches.

With the latter two examples, I'm still working on that :)

Edit: Wow I had that completely wrong, and I think you may have also. The issue is that `m/$./m` is *not* an end-of-line followed by a wildcard, but rather the variable $. interpolated as a regular expression. Yikes!