# Is it possible to write regular expression, evaluation of which will always fail?

Tags: java, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What regular expression can never match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845078/what-regular-expression-can-never-match)

I would like to write regular expression, which will match nothing, that is corresponding to empty language. Empty language is regular, so there should be a way to write regular expression for it.

I'm particularly interested in how to write it in Java using API provided by java.util.regex package (if possible), but any other language/API will be fine. I'm curious, if something like that is possible.

To clarify it once more, I want to find regular expression EMPTY_LANG_REGEX such that

```
Pattern.compile(EMPTY_LANG_REGEX).matcher(s).matches()
```

will yield *false* for every string *s*.

I know something like a++a works, but that is kind of hack and has performance issues.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845078/what-regular-expression-can-never-match

Comment: +1 Avi: nice find. They got all of the suggestion in my answer apart from one: `^\b$`, so I added the missing one on that thread. This one should be closed.

Answer (score 2):

To match no strings at all, not even then empty string:

```
^(?=a)b$
```

Another alternative that doesn't use lookaheads (doesn't work in multiline mode):

```
a^
```

One more way, using a negative character class that fails for every character:

```
^[^\S\s]$
```

For regex implementations that support matching on word boundaries, this will always fail because there won't be a word boundary inbetween the a characters in 'aa':

```
^a\ba$
```

Or simpler, and probably also fails to match in most regex implementations:

```
^\b$
```