# looking for the FALSE regex

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What regular expression can never match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845078/what-regular-expression-can-never-match)

I'm looking for a regular expression that will not match any string. 
Example:

suppose I have the following Java code

```
public boolean checkString(String lineInput, String regex)
{
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    final Matcher m = p.matcher(lineInput);
    return m.matches();
}
```

In some conditions I want that checkString will return false for all all lineInput.Cause I control only regex (and not lineInput) is there a value that will NOT match any string ?

-- Yonatan

Answer (score 2):

`\b\B` will not match any string since it's a contradiction.

`\b` is a zero-width anchor that matches the word boundary. `\B` is also zero-length, and sits wherever `\b` doesn't. Therefore it's simply impossible to witness `\b` and `\B` together.

If the regex flavor supports lookarounds, you can also use negative lookahead `(?!)`. This assertion will always fail since it's always possible to match an empty string.

As Java `String` literals, the patterns above are `"\\b\\B"` and `"(?!)"` respectively.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Word Boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), [Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try these old, esoteric characters that aren't really used anymore (although technically could be matched):

```
\f  The form-feed character ('\u000C')
\a  The alert (bell) character ('\u0007')
\e  The escape character ('\u001B')
```

Comment: Doesn't convey intent, and not 100% guaranteed to fail.

Answer (score 0):

I think the sensible way to do this would be like so:

```
private boolean noMatch = false;

public void setNoMatch(boolean nm) { noMatch = nm; }

public boolean checkString(String lineInput, String regex)
{
    if (noMatch) return false;
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    final Matcher m = p.matcher(lineInput);
    return m.matches();
}
```

Creating a non-matching regex sounds like a horrible kludge and an abuse of regex. If you know there won't be a match, then say so in your code! Your code will thank you for it by being more understandable and running faster.