# regular expression which returns false always

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What regular expression can never match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845078/what-regular-expression-can-never-match)

how do i write a regular expression which returns false always in php.

i wanted this bcos . i wanted to display a error msg with out a form rule...so i did like this..

```
if($values['result_msg'] == 'ERROR')
                    {
                    $form->registerRule('just_check','regex','/$^/');                       
                    $form->addRule('abc', 'Please enter valid Model Number.','just_check');
                    }
```

Comment: i don't see how practical this question is

Comment: for what reason? if(preg_match(...)) never_perform_this(); ??

Comment: +1 because it's the most ridiculous question i've ever seen in SO

Comment: I asked this once (for a good reason), but I can't find it. (nor remember the reason)

Comment: Considering that no valid `preg_match` pattern will **ever** return false (since the function returns an int number of matches), it's not possible without casting ;-) or using a borked regex (which will also throw a warning).  So you *could* do: `/foo` as the regex...

Comment: I'm out of close votes. Here's one dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845078/what-regular-expression-can-never-match

Comment: "I can't imagine a use case" doesn't imply  "dumb question".

Comment: It can be used as a filter that matches nothing, e.g. to implement an on/off filter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do it:

- `/(?=a)b/`

This fails to match because it searches for a character which is both a and b.

- `/\Zx\A/`

This fails to match because the end of the string cannot come before the start of the string.

- `/x\by/`

This fails to match because a word boundary cannot be between the characters `x` and `y`.

Comment: @Pekka: In PHP it's necessary to have a character between the $ and ^ otherwise it matches the empty string, `$x^` for example.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know *why* you want to do this, but this'll do it:

```
(?!x)x
```

The first bit `(?!`..`)` is a negative lookahead which says "make sure this position does not match the contents of this lookahead", where the contents is `x`, and then the final `x` says "match x" - since these two are opposites, the expression will never match.

You may also want to add start/end markers, i.e.

```
^(?!x)x$
```

You can swap both the `x` with pretty much anything, so long as both bits are equivalent.

There are plenty of other ways to do it, basically you just put two mutually exclusive conditions next to each other for matching the same place, and the regex will fail to match - see [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609321/regular-expression-which-returns-false-always/3609359#3609359) for more examples.

Comment: pradeep, there is an explanation there now. Although *you* haven't explained why you want this in the first place - there's probably a better solution.

Comment: @pradeep - @Peter told you what it was doing, what don't you understand?

Comment: slugster, StackOverflow doesn't show initial edits - there were four revisions to the post, not the one which the history currently shows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
$.^
```

Comment: If multiline dotall flag is enabled, would this not match a newline character?

Comment: @Peter: no. pay attention to the order of `$` and `^`.

Comment: nikic, pay attention to what I'm saying! If multiline flag is enabled, `$` matches "end of line" and `^` matches "start of line". If dotall flag is enabled `.` matches newline. Therefore, with multiline+dotall flags, `$.^` will match the newline (\n) character in `x\ny`.

Comment: (I've tested this with both Java and CF regex engines, and have verified this behaviour with those - I don't have a PHP setup handy to check for that.)

Comment: Ah hadn't thought of multiline! Thanks for the enlightenment Peter.