# Regular expression to check if two first words are same

Tags: php, regex

For example:

```
$s1 = "Test Test the rest of string"
$s2 = "Test the rest of string"
```

I would like to match positively `$s1` but not `$s2`, because first word in `$s1` is the same as second. Word `'Test'` is example, regular expression should work on any words.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if(preg_match('/^(\w+)\s+\1\b/',$input)) {
  // $input has same first two words.
}
```

Explanation:

```
^    : Start anchor
(    : Start of capturing group
 \w+ : A word
)    : End of capturing group
\s+  : One or more whitespace
\1   : Back reference to the first word
\b   : Word boundary
```

Answer (score 4):

```
~^(\w+)\s+\1(?:\W|$)~
~^(\pL+)\s+\1(?:\PL|$)~u // unicode variant
```

`\1` is a back reference to the first capturing group.

Comment: This expression gives a false positive for `Text Teststr`

Answer (score 1):

*Not working everywhere, see the comments...*

```
^([^\b]+)\b\1\b
^(\B+)\b\1\b
```

Gets the first word, and matches if the same word is repeated again after a word boundary.

Comment: A `\b` in character class is not word boundary but a backspace character.

Comment: @codaddict: Thanks, wasn't sure if it was like this or that :)

Comment: [`\b` and `\B`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) are zero width assertions, they will not match anything, certainly not next to each other. That said, you've inspired this: [What regular expression can never match?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845078/what-regular-expression-can-never-match/4850260#4850260)

Comment: Bleh, I have tested my original solution (`^([^\b]+)\b\1\b)`) in a language that does allow `\b` inside character classes (ActionScript), so matching any non-boundary did work; it matched the whole word including the following whitespace. Given that it doesn't work with `\B` I would delete this answer now, but I'll keep it for that inspiration reference ;)

Comment: It wasn't really non-boundary, in fact it was non-backspace! But then `\b` after that is a boundary and a little limiting, it means the first group, `\1`, must start with a word character and end with a non-word-character (or the other way around), so it will match `test!test!d`, for example, but not exactly for the reasons you think. `\1` includes the "space" here, which is `!`, which matches because it isn't a backspace! Here are a few more examples: http://rubular.com/r/1y239zNydK

Answer (score 1):

This does not cause `Test Testx` to return true.

```
$string = "Test Test";

preg_match('/^(\w+)\s+\1(\b|$)/', $string);
```