# Regex to *not* match any characters

Tags: regex

I know it is quite some weird goal here but for a quick and dirty fix for one of our system we do need to not filter any input and let the corruption go into the system.

My current regex for this is "`\^.*`"

The problem with that is that it does not match characters as planned ... but for one match it does work. The string that make it not work is ^@jj (basically anything that has ^ ... ).

What would be the best way to not match any characters now ? I was thinking of removing the `\`  but only doing this will transform the "not" into a "start with" ...

Comment: `\^` is not `not`, it's a literal `^`.

Comment: If you don't want to match anything, what do you need a regex for?

Comment: @Francisco business reasons, easier to deploy ;-)

Comment: If the regex for validation is derived from another part of a form entry, it is nice to have a default regex that will always fail if the form hasn't been fully populated yet. It's easier than having a special case.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The `^` character doesn't mean "not" except inside a character class (`[]`). If you want to not match anything, you could use a negative lookahead that matches anything: `(?!.*)`.

Comment: Seems to work ! But this construct (?! <= ) is quite weird to me, what does it means exactly ?

Comment: @Erick, read this page for info about lookaround operators: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html.

Comment: @JS Bang just started reading, sounds like something quite advanced but necessary. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: This might be more efficient:  /(?!a)a/   (Can't believe we're writing regexen to match nothing :))

Comment: @pilcrow business reasons ;-)

Comment: @Erick, ha!  If I may borrow from Pascal, the business has its reasons of which reason knows nothing.  :)  (Of course, reason alone usually doesn't lead to profit.)

Comment: Even more efficient: `(?!)` - the `.*` is optional anyway.

Comment: In terms of performance, is it a little better to go do the negative lookahead for `.?` instead of `.*` : `(?!.?)` ?

Comment: @leorleor But `(?!.?)` will match an empty string, while the version with `.*` will not.

Comment: @Erick re the earliest "sounds like something quite advanced but necessary" yeah I mean, there's a lot of ways for text to be formatted and a lot of queries and `replace()`s you'd want to do with it

I realize this comment is very old :sweat_smile: but I guess future readers can benefit from the discussion

Comment: Ooh, these resources will be useful for the typical SO user who just wants a quick (~=5 mins) fix: 1. [generally useful Regex from that tutorial pilcrow linked](https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) , 2. [a python use case for fellow pythonistas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-re-search-and-re-match) :)

Answer (score 62):

A simple and cheap regex that will never match anything is to match against something that is simply unmatchable, for example: `\b\B`.

It's **simply impossible** for this regex to match, since it's a contradiction.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info\Word Boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

  - `\B` is the negated version of `\b`. `\B` matches at every position where `\b` does not.

Comment: This is the usual solution, more widely-supported than lookaround.

Comment: OK, it's funny that there's a "usual solution" to this. =)

Comment: @MichaelH. it's actually really useful.  Say, I have a CLI with a "hide regex" parameter to exclude items from output. I want this to be off by default. So I could set the value to be empty by default, and have extra logic to enable the matching only when user provided it ---- or simply set `\b\B` as default value.

Comment: [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2302992/719276) might be more efficient: `^\b$`. Maybe a mix of the two would also work in emacs `^\b\B$`.

Answer (score 14):

Another very well supported and fast pattern that would fail to match anything that is guaranteed to be constant time:

`$unmatchable pattern` `$anything goes here` etc.

`$` of course indicates the end-of-line. No characters could possibly go after `$` so no further state transitions could possibly be made. The additional advantage are that your pattern is intuitive, self-descriptive and readable as well!

Comment: The negative lookahead solution is fine as well: I think as regexp goes, people understand `(?!.*)` a lot better. `$whatever` has a WTF factor to it ;)

Comment: This answer is more portable in that it also works in regex engines which don't *have* lookahead, although I think there are some multi-line modes where it can still match. I agree `$whatever` is a strange regex to look at, mostly because it looks like a variable expansion. But the same technique works the other way around - trying to match something before the start of the line: `whatever^`.

Comment: $whatever only looks like variable expansions in a limited number of languages like PHP and Perl — that won't be an issue if you're working with a codebase with the other languages. Good alternative!

Comment: In many implementations of regex `$` only means end when it is at the end of the regex (otherwise it's a literal).

Answer (score 8):

tldr; The **most portable and efficient** regex to never match anything is `$-` (*end of line followed by a char*)

---

## Impossible regex

The most reliable solution is to create an *impossible regex*. There are many impossible regexes but not all are as good.

First you want to **avoid "lookahead" solutions** because some regex engines don't support it.

Then you want to make sure your "impossible regex" is efficient and **won't take too much computation steps to match... nothing.**

I found that `$-` has a constant computation time ( O(1) ) and only takes **two steps** to compute regardless of the size of your text (https://regex101.com/r/yjcs1Z/3).

#### For comparison:

- `$^` and `$.` both take 36 steps to compute -> O(1)
- `\b\B` takes 1507 steps on my sample and increase with the number of character in your string -> O(n)

## Empty regex (alternative solution)

If your regex engine accepts it, the best and simplest regex to never match anything might be: an **empty regex**  .

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to not match any characters, why not just match all characters? `^.*$` should do the trick.  If you have to not match any characters then try `^\j$` (Assuming of course, that your regular expression engine will not throw an error when you provide it an invalid character class.  If it does, try `^()$`.  A quick test with RegexBuddy suggests that this might work.

Comment: `^\j$` matches j all by itself.  `^()$` matches the empty string.

Comment: Depends on the regex implementation IIRC - some will throw, some will translate it to `j` and some will treat it as a non-existent character class (the engine that powers RegexBuddy, when I wrote this answer, for example).

Answer (score 0):

You want to match nothing *at all*? Neg lookarounds seems obvious, but can be slow, perhaps `^$` (matches empty string only) as an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

^ is only not when it's in class (such as [^a-z] meaning anything but a-z). You've turned it into a literal ^ with the backslash.

What you're trying to do is [^]*, but that's not legal. You could try something like

```
" {10000}"
```

which would match exactly 10,000 spaces, if that's longer than your maximum input, it should never be matched.

Comment: You don't say what regular expression variant you're using, make sure it supports {} as a repetition count before trying this. It works in Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
((?iLmsux))
```

Try this, it matches only if the string is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting ... the most obvious and simple variant:

## **`~^`**

.

https://regex101.com/r/KhTM1i/1

requiring usually only one computation step (failing directly at the start and being computational expensive only if the matched string begins with a long series of `~`) is not mentioned among all the other answers ... for 12 years.