# For a dataframe column, how to replace all the unnormal values to 'NaN'

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

For a dataframe named `rawfile`, we have a `?` in the "workclass" column. We use the code `rawfile.replace("?", "NaN")` to replace all the `?` with a `NaN`. But what if there are other unnormal values other than `?`, like `-`. `@`. How can I detect them and replace them?

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for showing your efforts in form of code. Please do add your samples in form of text so that we could test our solutions it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex in the replace method. Set the value to be what you want, but in the code below it is set to be `np.NaN` but you could use a string of `NaN` if desired.

```
df['workclass'] = df['workclass'].replace(to_replace = '\@|\?' , value=np.NaN, regex = True)
```

Comment: what if there are many any unknown unnormal values except \@|\?. Are there a function to summary it all?

Comment: You could use regex to exclude values that do not fit the pattern. Here is an answer that goes into the details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2930209/4352317

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the types of normal and not normal values you expect. If there is not some prepared set of answers you should use regex. On the other hand, if there are only answers specified in advance then you can use construction

```
df.loc[~df["workclass"].isin(allowed_answers), "workclass"] = np.NaN
```

I also recommend using `np.NaN` instead of `"NaN"` as `np.NaN` is not read as string.