# A simple Perl regex guaranteed to never match a string?

Tags: regex, perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A Regex that will never be matched by anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723182/a-regex-that-will-never-be-matched-by-anything)

I have a script that takes a regex as a parameter. By default I want to set the regex to something that will never match any string, so I can simply say

```
if ($str =~ $regex)
```

without e.g. having to check defined($regex) first.

I came up with

```
qr/[^\s\S]/
```

but don't know if this will match some utf8 character that is neither a space nor a non-space.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
/(?!)/
```

http://perl.plover.com/yak/regex/samples/slide049.html

Comment: MJD’s solution is better than anything else offered here or on the alleged dup question that this deserves to be kept.

Comment: @tchrist: From my admittedly narrow point of view, just about anything by MJD is pure gold. The man is a Perl Alchemist or something.

Comment: To illuminate: the empty pattern `//` or `(?:)` doesn't assert anything, and therefore always matches. `(?!)` is a negative lookahead for the empty pattern (what comes between the `!` and the `)` is the body of the assertion) and therefore can never match.

Comment: @hobbs: Nitpick: // *can* match something; it's the special empty pattern, which will reuse the last matched regex if there was one... :(

Comment: @Hugmeir yeah, I didn't mean *that* `//`, but I guess it's a bit unclear :)

Answer (score 5):

Combine a negative lookahead for an arbitrary character followed by a match for that character, e.g.

```
/(?!x)x/
```

Works on all the test cases I threw at it. Here are some tests on [rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/YXXZGd0r2x).

Answer (score 4):

`/ ^/` seems to do, and is short(est).