# Listing all patterns that a regex matches

Tags: python, regex, perl

I am looking for a way to list all possible patterns from a finite regex (with no duplicates). Is there any source available?

Comment: @Artha Any language preference?

Comment: Can you give an example of input and expected output?

Comment: Do you mean all possible matches from a regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it won't cover some advanced features, and has its own share of other caveats, [Regexp::Genex](http://search.cpan.org/~bowmanbs/Regexp-Genex-0.07/lib/Regexp/Genex.pm) seems to be close to what you are looking for.

There's also [this thread of PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=656880) which is relevant enough (as well as explaining how Regexp::Genex might not do for you, and some roll-yourself alternatives).

Otherwise, as per Jeffrey Friedl's [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565922570), you could use the /g modifier, coupled with the (?{CODE}) extension and a [pattern that will never match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589405/a-simple-perl-regex-guaranteed-to-never-match-a-string/4589566#4589566), ala:

```
perl -E '$_ = 'Mastering Regular Expressions'; /(\p{L}*)(?{ say qq![$^N]! })(?!)/g;'
```

Comment: Is there any fully developed code -- Regex::Genex was alpha and does not support ^ $ \G...

Comment: Not that I know, unfortunately - Maybe a combination of that example from Mastering Regular Expressions (if you really, really needed it, you could even use $& and friends instead of capturing groups.. I don't know whenever $^{MATCH} works inside (?{CODE}) blocks) plus String::Random could do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

A Haskell program based on Perl's `Regexp::Genex` can be found [on Github](https://github.com/audreyt/regex-genex) and [on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-genex).

[According to the author](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2586475), it was inspired by Regexp::Genex, but "uses a random-walk approach for character classes, instead of enumerating all possibilities."