# Regex matching no strings

Tags: regex

Does there exist a regular expression that matches no strings? If so, what is it?

To be precise, I'm looking for a regular expression `r` such that the following Python code outputs `True` for any string `s`:

```
import re
print(re.match(r, s) is None)
```

Comment: Can you just use isinstance(s,str) method?

Comment: No, I cannot. Only `r` and `s` may vary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A Regex that will never be matched by anything](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723182/a-regex-that-will-never-be-matched-by-anything)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your regex engine supports lookahead (which Python's does):

```
(?!)
```

Otherwise something like this would work too:

```
^\b$
```

A word break can't occur by itself!

Or,

```
$a^
```

The end of the string can't match at the start of the string unless the string is empty, and we prevent it from being empty by requiring that we match at least one character.

Then again, `^`/`$`/`\b` are really just lookarounds in disguise.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for. I meant a regular expression in the [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) sense. I probably should have posted this on [cs.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Lookaheads are regular, they do not extend the power of the language.

Comment: But I've added another example too :)

Comment: @tripleee: that matches the empty string. Both ^ and $ are zero-length matches.

Answer (score 1):

The following regex should match no strings. It will match any single character which is neither a whitespace character, nor a nonwhitespace character.

```
[^\S\s]
```