# How to set up REGEX that doesn't match anything?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Just for curiosity.

Is it possible to create a regular expression that will not match any string, including an empty string?

Comment: With [true regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Patterns_for_non--regular_languages), technically the empty set is a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_language_theory).

Comment: I guess it is the same point as having `NULL`, `undef` or `None`: sometimes you want to have compiled regex as starting value that never matches anything

Comment: @mvp Exactly! (I wrote this to avoid limitation)

Comment: @GillBates, I removed your remark about the closure from the question. It should be a comment. You may be right that it shouldn't have been closed, but you got your answer, so it doesn't really matter, does it?

Comment: @Mischa: this is rather strange attitude. If you think that it should not have been closed, question is clear, good answer exists, why you close it as `not a real question`? If may not matter for this user right now, but it WILL matter to other users who will read this question later.

Comment: @mvp, once you vote to close, you cannot undo it. I had already voted to close, but later when I read all comments and answers I thought I shouldn't have.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes.

Here are a few examples.

```
.^
$.
(?!)
```

Naturally, there are an infinite number of such expressions.

Comment: @Pterodactyl Certainly. Example: `.^`, `..^`, `...^`, etc.

Comment: About performance of the examples in Javascript / PHP : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70670013/7514010

Answer (score 2):

This regex should never match anything (provided you do not use single-line or multi-line modifiers):

```
$x^
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will match an empty string.

Comment: Well, I tried Perl flavor, and it does not match empty string

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22011/discussion-between-kendall-frey-and-mvp)

Comment: @GillBates Wow, that is certainly strange. Which engine are you using? .NET does match, but JavaScript doesn't.

Comment: @Gill Bates - its about '$^' version

Answer (score 0):

How about `/^$x/.`  When I try it with ruby, it seems to work.