# Regex - only matching wildcard of a certain length or less

Tags: c#, regex, wildcard, maxlength

Is there a way to have a Regex statement search for a wildcard with a maximum length? For instance:

```
somestuff.*morestuff
```

If I wanted the above to match

```
somestuffblahmorestuff
```

but not

```
somestuffblahblahmorestuff
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To match a known length use `.{2,5}` where the 2 is the minimum number of characters and 5 is the max. both values are optional but you do need one or the other

More can be read on this topic [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Answer (score 2):

In regex:

> ***`{n}`*** 
> Matches the previous element exactly `n` times.

> ***`{n,}`*** 
> Matches the previous element at least `n` times.

> ***`{n,m}`*** 
> Matches the previous element at least `n` times, but no more than `m` times.

For example:

**`,\d{3}`** matches `,876`, `,543`, and `,210` in `9,876,543,210`

**`\d{2,}`** matches `166`, `29`, `1930`

**`\d{3,5}`** matches `19302` in `193024`

Comment: This answer has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Quantifiers"

Answer (score 0):

```
somestuff.{4,7}morestuff
```

{min, max} is the syntax to specify the number of repetition.