# Python re.finditer match.groups() does not contain all groups from match

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use regex in Python to find and print all matching lines from a multiline search.
The text that I am searching through may have the below example structure:

```
AAA
ABC1
ABC2
ABC3
AAA
ABC1
ABC2
ABC3
ABC4
ABC
AAA
ABC1
AAA
```

From which I want to retrieve the **ABC***s that occur at least once and are preceeded by an **AAA**.

The problem is, that despite the group catching what I want:

```
match = <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(19, 38), match='AAA\nABC2\nABC3\nABC4\n'>
```

... I can access only the last match of the group:

```
match groups = ('AAA\n', 'ABC4\n')
```

Below is the example code that I use for this problem.

```
#! python
import sys
import re
import os

string = "AAA\nABC1\nABC2\nABC3\nAAA\nABC1\nABC2\nABC3\nABC4\nABC\nAAA\nABC1\nAAA\n"
print(string)

p_MATCHES = []
p_MATCHES.append( (re.compile('(AAA\n)(ABC[0-9]\n){1,}')) ) #   
matches = re.finditer(p_MATCHES[0],string)

for match in matches:
    strout = ''
    gr_iter=0
    print("match = "+str(match))
    print("match groups = "+str(match.groups()))
    for group in match.groups():
    gr_iter+=1
    sys.stdout.write("TEST GROUP:"+str(gr_iter)+"\t"+group) # test output
    if group is not None:
        if group != '':
            strout+= '"'+group.replace("\n","",1)+'"'+'\n'
sys.stdout.write("\nCOMPLETE RESULT:\n"+strout+"====\n")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is your regular expression:

```
(AAA\r\n)(ABC[0-9]\r\n){1,}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/T2rlW8dO_d7Sm6jA)

Your goal is to capture *all* `ABC#`s that immediately follow `AAA`. As you can see in this Debuggex demo, all `ABC#`s are indeed being matched (they're highlighted in yellow). However, since only the "what is being repeated" part

```
ABC[0-9]\r\n
```

is being [captured](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21880127) (is inside the parentheses), and its [quantifier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17120435),

```
{1,}
```

is not being captured, this therefore causes all matches *except the final one* to be discarded. To get them, you must also capture the quantifier:

```
AAA\r\n((?:ABC[0-9]\r\n){1,})
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/h3WCCQv-ek1K5VTJ)

I've placed the "what is being repeated" part (`ABC[0-9]\r\n`) into a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471). (I've also stopped capturing `AAA`, as you don't seem to need it.)

The captured text can be split on the newline, and will give you all the pieces as you wish.

(Note that `\n` by itself doesn't work in Debuggex. It requires [`\r\n`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3451192).)

---

This is a workaround. Not many regular expression flavors offer the capability of iterating through repeating captures (which ones...?). A more normal approach is to loop through and *process* each match as they are found. Here's an example from Java:

```
   import java.util.regex.*;

public class RepeatingCaptureGroupsDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String input = "I have a cat, but I like my dog better.";

      Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(mouse|cat|dog|wolf|bear|human)");
      Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

      while (m.find()) {
         System.out.println(m.group());
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
cat
dog
```

*(From http://ocpsoft.org/opensource/guide-to-regular-expressions-in-java-part-1/, about a 1/4 down)*

---

Please consider bookmarking the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) for future reference. The links in this answer come from it.

Comment: That is a worthy workaround.
What I aimed at is to get an iterable set of groups like:

    match groups = ('AAA', 'ABC1', 'ABC2', 'ABC3',...)

What I get with this solution is

    match groups = ('AAA', 'ABC1\nABC2\nABC3\n')

Comment: sorry, I've tried upvoting but didn't have enough reputation. The answer helped indeed. I've built-in another set of loops as a workaround to get what I wanted. Not exactly how I wanted to solve it, but still a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You want the pattern of consecutive **ABC\n** occurring after a **AAA\n** in the most greedy way. You also want only the group of consecutive **ABC\n** and not a tuple of that and the most recent **ABC\n**. So in your regex, exclude the subgroup within the group.
Notice the pattern, write the pattern that represents the whole string.

```
AAA\n(ABC[0-9]\n)+
```

Then capture the one you are interested in with (), while remembering to exclude subgroup(s)

```
AAA\n((?:ABC[0-9]\n)+)
```

You can then use either findall() or finditer(). I find findIter easier especially when you are dealing with more than one capture.
finditer:-

```
import re
matches_iter = re.finditer(r'AAA\n((?:ABC[0-9]\n)+)', string)

[print(i.group(1)) for i in matches_iter]
```

findall, used the original {1,} as its a more verbose form of + :-

```
matches_all = re.findall(r'AAA\n((?:ABC[0-9]\n){1,})', string)

[[print(x) for x in y.split("\n")] for y in matches_all]
```