# Regex to only catch numbers which are greater than n digits in length

Tags: regex

I have regex that matches URL paths where there is a *number* in second part of the path.

```
(*/)([0-9]+)(/*)
```

However, I want to modify it to only matches paths where the second part is a number **and** is greater than 3 digits in length/ e.g.

```
/abcd/12345/abcd – Matched
/abcd/123/abcd – Not matched
```

Is there a way to specify length limits in regex?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17120435/5527985

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A URL consists of URL-encoded ASCII characters which are not control characters (see [W3Schools- URI Encoding reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP)).

The regex to match all printable ASCII characters (no control characters!) is the following (See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203190/regex-any-ascii-character)):

```
[ -~]
```

Therefore assuming you want to match the whole URL you can use the following regex:

```
^[ -~]*\/\d{4,}\/?[ -~]*$
```

- `^`: Matches begin of a string
- `[ -~]`: Any printable ASCII character
- `*`: Match zero or more of the preceding token
- `\/`: Slash, must be escaped in RegEx
- `\d`: Regex class for digits, matches all digits 0-9
- `{0,4}`: Matches 4 or more of the preceding token (at least three numbers)
- `?`: Matches 0 or 1 of the preceding token (there could be a slash at the end or not, both are matched)
- `$`: Matches end of a string

```js
const urls = [
  "/abcd/12345/abcd", // Matched
  "/12345/abcd",      // Matched
  "/abcd/123/abcd",   // Not matched - too less digits
  "12345/abcd",       // Not matched - must NOT start with a number (can be adjusted if required)
  "/abcd/12345",      // Matched - may end wiht a number (can be adjusted if required)
  "/abäd/1234"        // Not matched - invalid URL as 'ä' is a non-ASCII character
]

const isValidUrl = (url) => {
  const match = url.match(/^[ -~]*\/\d{4,}\/?[ -~]*$/);
  if(match === null) console.log(`URL ${url} does NOT match.`);
  else console.log(`Match found: ${match[0]}`);
}

urls.forEach(url => isValidUrl(url));
```

```css
/* StackOverflow snippet: console should overlap rendered HTML area */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

> It's not 100% clear what exactly you want to match so you might need to adjust the regex to your needs. I suggest you use this RegEx as a starting point and use [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) to refine it if required.

Comment: Thankyou Your answer addresses the actual question. However, just based on your comments `can be adjusted if required`. Is it possible to have a regex that matches the given condition that is a number greater than 3 in length in anywhere in URL, irrespective of whether its after first second of after nth `/`?

Comment: Two question: Do you want the match to only contain those numbers and do you want `12345/abdc` to match or only `/12345/abcd`?

Comment: My end goal is actually to match numbers irrespective of where they appear and to replace them with some other text. For the first part I understand we can mark separate groups in regex using `marked subexpressions ()` but not sure how to dynamically get that which part of the URL is a number, so i can replace it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this pattern:

```
 ^/[^/]+/\d{4,}
```

The `\d{4,}` ending portion of the regex matches only on 4 digits or more.  Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/FhFvBU/1).