# does a positive lookahead end a regular expression's ability to continue matching?

Tags: regex

from [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (emphasis added)

> Let's take one more look inside, to make sure you understand the
>   implications of the lookahead. Let's apply q(?=u)i to quit. The
>   lookahead is now positive and is followed by another token. Again, q
>   matches q and u matches u. **Again, the match from the lookahead must be
>   discarded, so the engine steps back from i in the string to u. The
>   lookahead was successful, so the engine continues with i. But i cannot
>   match u.** So this match attempt fails. All remaining attempts fail as
>   well, because there are no more q's in the string.

does this necessarily mean that the match has to stop after this `q` not followed by a `u` is matched? What can come after once the `q` is matched? What if we want to perform more matches after this `q` not followed by a `u`? eg, if I want to continue to match the rest of the letters in the word quote? `q(?=u)ote`.

Comment: It would still fail continue to fail..

Comment: I don't see why you're over complicating things. `(?=u)` asserts that there is an `u` ahead, if it exists it will continue but then the regex states that it needs to match `i` which is never true if the lookahead succeeded. So basically this is something like `10 > 20`. It's always false. [This post might be funny](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723182/a-regex-that-will-never-be-matched-by-anything)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, once the lookahead assertion fails then the match stops. In that sense they're no different from any other part of a regex - if they don't "match" then the overall match fails. The difference is that the matching characters are not consumed by the match, so the following part of the regex (if there is one) still needs to match those characters.

In this case the `u` matches the lookahead `(?=u)`, but the `u` isn't consumed by the match. Therefore in the next step the `u` is tested against the `i` and the overall match fails. Using `q(?=u)` means the `q` must be followed by a `u`. To match `quit` using a similar regex you could use `q(?=u)uit`.

If you want to match after a `q` not followed by a `u` then you could use a negative lookahead instead of a positive lookahead, e.g. `q(?!u)ote` would match `qote`, but these examples are contrived. Lookaheads (and Lookbehinds) are very useful but they take some getting used to, and they're not needed in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: Hm. So in what sense is `/q(?=u)uit/` different than simply `/q(?=u)uit/`? :(

Comment: I wrote that last comment wrong. Should have been: "So in what sense is `/q(?=u)uit/` different than simply `/quit/` ?"

Comment: @thomas There isn't a difference, which is why it's a contrived example. I very rarely use positive lookaheads, because the desired outcome can often be achieved in a simpler way.

Comment: Perhaps because you can plug an additional regex into the lookahead parenthesis you might achieve something pretty clever.