# MySQL not rlike clause returns error 'empty (sub)expression' from regexp

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have a problem in my condition in the following `where` clause (on the last line):

```
create procedure getSubjects(IN excludeName VARCHAR(255))
begin
    select *

    from subject

    where excludeName = '' or subject.name not rlike excludeName;
end
```

No error is reported when I store the procedure, but I get `ERROR 1139 (42000) at line 1: Got error 'empty (sub)expression' from regexp` whenever I call the procedure without empty parameters.

How can I write this clause?

**Note:**

I get the same error with the following syntax:

```
create procedure getSubjects(IN excludeName VARCHAR(255))
begin
    select *
    from subject
    where 
        case excludeName
            when '' then 
                subject.name rlike '.*' 
            else
                subject.name not rlike excludeName
            end;
end
```

Comment: Revert the condition: `if(includeName != '', includeName, '.*')`. Else section will be applied to both empty string (condition is false) and NULL (condition is NULL which is treated as false). The same with second condition.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using [a regexp which never matches anything](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2302992/719276) (`^\b\B$`) giving the following syntax:

```
create procedure getSubjects(IN excludeName VARCHAR(255))
begin
    select *
    from subject
    where subject.name not rlike if(excludeName is null or excludeName = '', '^\b\B$', excludeName);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `IFNULL()` to replace a null value with a default.

```
create procedure getSubjects(IN includeName VARCHAR(255), 
                             IN excludeName VARCHAR(255))
begin
    select *
    from subject
    where subject.name rlike if(IFNULL(includeName, '') = '', '.*', includeName)
    and (IFNULL(excludeName, '') = '' or subject.name not rlike excludeName);
end
```

Comment: I'll remove the first part of the clause (which works fine) in my question, to focus on the error.